# How does windows OS knows whether a program is used rarely or occasionally or frequently?

Tags: windows-xp, windows

For Windows XP, in Control Panel--> Add or Remove Programs, there are listed programs installed in os. Click on it we can see information like 'Used: occasionally' or 'Used: rarely' or 'Used:frequently'. I want to get this information too. Does anybody know how windows store these information(through registry or any other ways)?